# plotly dash write image of chart issue

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

i am trying to save the snapshot image of a plotly chart in dash with multiple traces and y axes to a png file using plotly.io.write_image. In my callback function i am passing the state of the figure to the function and its giving me the following error:

`ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.layout.xaxis.Rangeslider: 'yaxis2'`

Here is my dash callback function:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('debug2', 'children'),
    Input('report-cx-btn', 'n_clicks'),
    [State('b-chart1', 'figure')],
)
def handle_page(report_button, fig):

    ctx = dash.callback_context

    if not ctx.triggered:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        triggered = ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0]
        debug = "triggered is {}".format(triggered)

        if str(triggered) == "report-cx-btn":
            debug += "got report button {} times".format(report_button)

            # write current chart image file to dir
            plotly.io.write_image(fig=fig,
                                  file="/home/mos377/ci_dev/images/fig1.png"
                                  width=1280,
                                  height=720,
                                  scale=1)

            return debug
        else:
            raise PreventUpdate
```

When i use the chart modebar option 'download plot as png' that works fine to give me an image of the chart snapshot, but I really need to be able to control that externally from the chart so that i can create a pdf report that contains the latest chart snapshot image. I would really appreciate any help/suggestions anyone could offer!

Thanks

Comment: You are missing a comma in your `write_image` function call. Apart from that I can't reproduce the problem. It probably has to do with the value of `fig`, can you share what `fig` is. If you set the value of `fig` to a simple figure of a bar chart with dummy values, does it work?

Comment: Thanks, it was a configuration issue - I took out the rangeslider configuration (which i was hiding anyway) and that appears to have fixed the issue.

Comment: It seems to have been this line ```'rangeslider': {'visible': False, 'yaxis': {}, 'yaxis2': {}}``` that was causing the issue.